# Calculate age from date of birth with formatting

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to calculate the age from the date of birth stored as a string using the format in the comments in the code. Here's my code:

```
--pnr values
--'19490321-7000'
--'19540201-7000'
--'19650823-7000'

declare
v_now date :=to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
v_dob date;
v_age number;
cursor c_carowners is select fnamn, enamn, pnr
                      from carowners;
begin
  for v_rec in c_carowners loop

    v_dob:= to_date(substr(v_rec.pnr,1,8), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    v_age := (months_between(v_now, v_dob))/12;

    dbms_output.put_line('Age is: '||v_age);

  end loop;
end;
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Statement processed.
Age is: -1935.252688172043010752688172043010752692
Age is: -1940.115591397849462365591397849462365592
Age is: -1951.674731182795698924731182795698924733
```

I guess there's something wrong with the year but I can't figure it out!

Comment: mysql is not plsql. I suppose this has nothing to do with mysql?

Comment: That's right, I edited the tags now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
v_now date :=to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You should not call `to_date` on `sysdate`, because `sysdate` *already* has the data type `date`.

You should just do:

```
v_now date := sysdate;
```

Or, even leave out that variable, and use `sysdate` directly in your calculation.

I would also change the other date format to `YYYYMMDD`, since your table data has no hyphens.

Note that you can do this without PL/SQL, with a query:

```
select pnr,
       months_between(sysdate, to_date(substr(pnr,1,8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/12
from   carowners;
```

Comment: Of course! It works perfectly, thx a lot!